# CREATE FUNCTION must be the first statement in query batch. A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sql-function, reportbuilder

I am unable to use sql functions inside query provided to SSRS report using Microsoft Report Builder. Same query works fine in SSMS.

Error:

> CREATE FUNCTION must be the first statement in query batch. A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context

Query:

> ```
> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS o19.GetISTDate;
> Declare @UTCDate datetime;
> SET @UTCDate = NULL;
> GO
> CREATE FUNCTION o19.GetISTDate(@UTCDate datetime) RETURNS datetime
> AS
> BEGIN
>     RETURN @UTCDate + CAST('05:30' as datetime)
> END;
> GO
> Select o19.GetISTDate('22-July-2022')
> GO
> ```

[Error in SSRS report using Report Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RasN4.png)

Comment: The word "go" is evaluated by the SSMS client tool and means "this is the end of a batch, send all of the text up to here to the server all at once". The word "go" doesn't mean anything to SQL Server, it's not part of the T-SQL language. Sending all of that query text to SQL Server will result in an incorrect syntax error, as well as the two errors you provided. I don't know the report builder tool, but what I think you want to do is create the function in SSMS first and then just *call* it in the report.

Comment: Why are you re-creating a function in a query within SSRS? Why not just create the function permanently in the database and then just call it from your dataset query?